# Loading data before Webservice callouts?

Tags: unit-test, webservices, webservicemock

I need Opportunity record to be inserted in test class and then use that Id in webservice call out. Tried every different combination but it asks me **commit the DML operation  before doing webservice call out** and test class fails. Is there any standard way of data creation before doing webservice callout test ?

Here is my code:

```
@isTest
public class className_Test{

public static Opportunity doDML()
{
    //Logic to insert required records
}

 public static testMethod void  TestInterfaceCallout()
{
    Opportunity opp = doDML(); 
   //Mock implementation called 
   Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new TestInterface_MockImpl());

   Test.startTest();
   WebserviceCls.WebServiceMethod(opp.Id);
   Test.stopTest();
}
```

Is there anything I am missing or is that impossible to do  ?

Comment: Have you tried making the Opportunity a static variable outside of the testMethod? Like `static Opportunity opp = doDML();`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can set up data prior to making the callout but you have to wrap the setmock inside the test.starttest();

Wrapping it in the test.starttest starts a new transaction so you will not get the error. **NOTE** This still does not work if you are executing a batch inside the block. If it is a batch you will have to call the start, execute, and finish methods separately.(Still a bug)

Like so:

```
public static testMethod void  TestInterfaceCallout()
{
    Opportunity opp = doDML(); 

   Test.startTest();
   //Mock implementation called 
   Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new TestInterface_MockImpl());
   WebserviceCls.WebServiceMethod(opp.Id);
   Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a web service callout after a DML operation in the same transaction. 
try this code:-

```
@isTest
public class className_Test{

public static Opportunity doDML()
{
//Logic to insert required records
}

public static testMethod void  TestInterfaceCallout()
{
  Opportunity opp = doDML(); 

   Test.startTest();
  Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new TestInterface_MockImpl());
  WebserviceCls.WebServiceMethod(opp.Id);
  Test.stopTest();
}
}
```